# How to construct a UML diagram for a simple chess game with GUI?

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, uml, class-diagram

I'm currently doing a course in Object Oriented programming in Java, and we need to create a game for our last lab so my lab partner an me chose to make a 2 player chess game without AI and using the model-view-controller approach.

We are a little bit lost as how and where to start so we need a simple UML diagram so we know where to start.

We have come up with the following classes, but aren't sure if they are enough or if all the data fields and methods make sense:

[image]

- `ChessBoard` (model) class and `ChessLogic` class (?)
- `View` class to present data from the model class
- `Controller` class that updates the model data as well as the `View` class based on user input
- An abstract `Piece` class or interface which is inherited or implemented by each of the 6 pieces.

Comment: Two quick obsevations: 1) there don't appear to be any references to `Piece`s anywhere in the `ChessBoard` class; how will you record what pieces are on the board and where they are located? 2) it doesn't look like you've made any provision for distinguishing White pieces from Black.

Comment: 1. There aren't any multiplicities. 2. An interface without any operations doesn't make sense. 3. An operation to make a move is missing.

Comment: I think you're totally lost. What kind of chess is that? Ever since it has 8x8 fields which can be occupied with figures. There's nothing which can express that.

Comment: Well i have never made a program completely from scratch without instructions, therefore i needed someone who's good at that to provide a UML diagram for a relatively simple 2 player chess game cause i know my UML diagram has many problems. But maybe thats asking for too much..

Answer (score 0):

This diagram is a nice start but there's still a lot to be done.  I will draw your attention on some points you need to improve, but without preventing you from learning by doing.

First some formalities:

- use the arrows for the relationships only to indicate [navigability](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#navigability). If the link is bidirectional, either use 2 arrows or none. For example, here we could understand that `View` knows `ChessBoard`, but it is not clear if `ChessBoard` knows about `Views`: how can the `ChessBoard` then inform `Views` that the state of the board has changed after a move was done ?
- indicate the [multiplicity](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html?context=class-diagrams): for exemple, I wonder if it is one `ChessBoard` for one `View` or could there be several `Views` for a same `Chessboard` ?
- avoid ambiguity between associations and properties.  For example, in `View`, you have a `model` property of type ChessBoard.  But you also have an association with `ChessBoard`.  So is this all the same `ChessBoard` ?  Or do we have two `ChessBoard`s, one associated and one embedded ? It would be clearer to remove the `model` from the properties, and indicate `model` as the name of the asscoiated object at the [end of the association](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#association-end).
- The association starting from `Controller` that suddenly splits into two is not very practical, especially if you'll tell us about association ends and multiplicity.  Prefer to visually have two very distinct lines .

Now to the core:

- Your model should not just be a `ChessBoard`.  The model should be a `Game` that has a couple of elements.  `ChessBoard` is only one of them:  the current position of the `Piece`s.  But what about the `layers` ? Where are they ?  How do I know that it's two of them ?  How does the Controller know wo's turn it is ?
- By calling something `ChessBoard` that is more than a chess board, you might create a confusion.  For example,  can the board know for sure if `isGameOver()`, just with the information on the position of the pieces ?  Isn't it possible that a player decides to abandon ?  So try to name your classes according to what they really represent.
- How can I find out which `Pieces` are where on the board ?
- How do I know the [color](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Color) of a `Piece`  ?
- How can I find out if a board's cell is free or occupied ?
- What happens if a Piece is removed from the board because it was taken ?

Your UML diagram must evolve to clarify all this.  So I think to complete the [`ChessBoard`](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Chessboard) and the [`Piece`](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Pieces) you're missing at least `Game`, `Player`, `BoardCell` (also called "[Square](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Squares)", and perhap's some containers of `Pieces` still on the board for each player.

Once you've completed, you also need to think about the relation between the Model, the View and the Controler, to be sure that the Controller knows enough to give commands to the model, but also that the model can inform the View when something has changed.

*P.S:  I've added some links to a the [Chess Programming Wiki](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Chess) since this website describes well some elementary concepts for programming the game, some [usual questions](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Board_Representation) as well as a lot of references.  But be aware however that although very informative this resource is not very object oriented.*